# Cannot run my application

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a simple android application interface in Android studio. I'm following few tutorials online.

here some images about something that i'm trying to accomplish:
[image: Gradle Preview]

I'm simply do not know where exactly where i'm wrong. I've checked multiple times, but my application won't run.

here's the link for the code:
  [MainActivity.java](https://pastebin.com/kAwMkmmg),
  [activity_main.xml](https://pastebin.com/50u9ettv)

here is inside my build.gradle (module.app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pam.pohat_4"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    //Libary
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

but i get this un-ending error:
[image: logcat]

Answer (score 0):

There is a miss type match between your **XML button(line no: 30 and 45)** and button initialization you have done in your MainActivity.onCreate() (Line no: 10, 17 and 18).

Choose which type you want to use **info.hoang8f.widget.FButton** or **Button**.